# setValue() not saving data to my realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save data to my realtime database using the setValue() methods but it's not saving my object.

I tried with a simple String and still didn't worked.

My code :

```
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference();
        ref.setValue("user");
Toast.makeText(RegisterApp.this, "Passe tranquille #1! Ref = " + ref.toString() + " | Db = " + db.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The makeText is called and show me good information which (should) show that it's connected to the database?

But still my realtime db shown null instead of string "user".

build.graddle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.graddle with version set by myself

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.projetl3"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "guava", module: "guava"
        implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
        implementation.exclude module:'protolite-well-known-types'
        implementation.exclude module:'guava'
        implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-lite'

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha04"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha04"
// CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha24"


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision'

    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev357-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
}
```

app/build.graddle with bom version :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.projetl3"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "guava", module: "guava"
        implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
        implementation.exclude module:'protolite-well-known-types'
        implementation.exclude module:'guava'
        implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-lite'

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha04"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha04"
// CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha24"


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision'

    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev357-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
}
```

My rules : ( I even tried to put them to true, or even "true")

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1623794400000",  // 2021-6-16
    ".write": "now < 1623794400000",  // 2021-6-16
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Map for adding data to the database, as @ahmad bajwa suggested in his answer, or you can use a model class. Seeing that you want to write some user data, at a minimum, the declaration of the class should look like this:

```
class User {
    public String userName;
}
```

Now to write the data to the Realtime Database, please use the following lines of code:

```
User user = new User("Constant Abrh");
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
usersRef.child("firstUser").setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User added successfully.");
        } else {
            Log.d"(TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Always consider attaching a listener to see the result, because there are cases in which the write operation might not succeed, Firebase servers might reject the write operation, for example. In the end, you database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- firstUser
             |
             --- name: "Constant Abrh"
```

If you want, you can also consider implementing [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), so you can write later [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Comment: Thank you i'll try your code, I did create Firebase Authentification and worked, in fact my problem was to register my User class, but here I cannot even save a simple String even tho i'm following videos/forums codes, I updated my post maybe you'll find my problem

Comment: Yes, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I guess your second Log.d(TAG) should be replaced by "TAG" and your Task<DataSnapshot> with Task<Void>

Comment: I might change your Log to a Toast.makeText because i'm not using my computer to start an Android Emulator / using USB devices to test my app but i'm building APK then updating my app on my phone directly

Comment: That's not a problem to change the log statement with a Toast message.  Have you tried the code? Does it work?

Comment: For some reason, it worked even tho it looks exactly the same as I tried before, there was also an Hello World from before that worked, it might be because I upgraded my Firebase BOM to 20.0.1 today, but small problem is it should appear in another project, I changed my google-services.json but it went to my old projet which I linked before, is there a way to change that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. but please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks mate for giving the some credit.

Answer (score 3):

Check this article on medium where there is explanation for why setValue would fail.
https://medium.com/@valokafor/firebase-realtime-database-by-example-with-android-1e597819e24b . You might want to check Firebase rules

Comment: Forgot to mention that my rules have been both set to true, so it should work but still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Map` to add values in firebase Realtime database. As firebase Realtime database work just like `json`.

```
   DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference();
    Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<>();
    users.put("user",   "Alan Turing");
    ref.setValueAsync(users);
```

For more details you at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast reply, but I do not have the setValueAsync, did I miss something or is it my setValue ?

Comment: you can use setValue also. setValueAsync is same as setValue just it work as async task.

Comment: But still don't work using setValue(), setValueAsync() is outdated I guess since it's not available, my rules are set to true, I even tried to create another Firebase projet, I tried with Map<> like said in firebase docs, I even tried the one from Firebase Assisstant in Android Studio, but still no data saved

Comment: setValueAsync is not outdated its in their official website. Try to update your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is in a non-default region, make sure you add the database link in the getInstance code.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here")
```

In my case this was the reason, so make sure you aren't making the same mistake.